# How can i stop a remote build in Jenkins if a parameter in the url is not valid?

Tags: jenkins

I run remote builds in Jenkins as follows:

```
JENKINS_URL/job/JOBNAME/build?token=TOKEN
```

If i add an extra parameter on the query string as follows:

```
JENKINS_URL/job/JOBNAME/build?token=TOKEN&User=test@test.com&Key=Wxfder$324
```

As the first step in the build I want to extract these values ie token, User and Key and do some validation and if not valid , then stop the job.

Is there a Build Step i can use, how can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by passing the data you need appending to the build cause. Refer to the following example.

**The URL**
Note the content assigned to `cause=` parameter

```
http://localhost:8080/job/Scripted/build?token=12345678&cause=User:test@test.com,Key:Wxfder$324
```

**The Pipeline**

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def cause = currentBuild.getBuildCauses()[0]
                    def note = cause.getString("note")
                    echo "${note}"
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above will give you the following Output.

```
[Pipeline] echo
User:test@test.com,Key:Wxfder$324
```

Comment: Is it the same in a  FreeStyle job ? do i need to do this in a Groovy script ?

Comment: Yes should be same for Freestyle. AFAIK easiest way to do is by using a groovy script.